# mysql update id value from another table + current id

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. lets say Table and BackupTable
And i want to Update the id of Table with the last id from BackupTable.
because BackupTable holds all the data of Table. And table is being deleted after the data was inserted and then deleted.

This is what i have as a command.

```
update Table set id = CONCAT((SELECT id FROM BackupTable
ORDER BY BackupTable.id ASC) + id);
```

it gives me an error:

```
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

and from there i know how to add the data from Table to Backuptable.

Comment: what is the use of CONCAT in this query ?

Comment: You read the whole BackupTable. The error message is quite clear, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

nevermind...so stupid of me :)) i was selecting all the id's from that table
this is it.... i had to select the last inserted id.

```
update phubChannelRank set id = CONCAT((SELECT max(id) FROM ArchiveTheSeeker.phubChannelRank) + id);
```

Comment: This looks like an accident waiting to happen